# Running R via Batch results in "No such file or directory"

Tags: r, file, batch-file, shiny

This Batch-File starts my Shiny-App app.R:

```
set RSCRIPT="C:\ [path to R] \Rscript.exe"
set RSCRIPT_FILE="G:\ [path to script] \app.R"

%RSCRIPT% %RSCRIPT_FILE%

PAUSE
```

In the console I see, that the R-File is executed (Packages are attached and so on), until the script loads a file. It says that it can't open "G:/ [path to file] /data.csv": "No such file or directory". When I run app.R in RStudio, everything works fine. Others seem to encounter similar problems when running R via Batch but I could not find a solution to the problem.

Someone suggested an alternate Batch-File:

```
"C:\ [path to R] \R.exe" CMD BATCH "G:\ [path to script] \app.R"
PAUSE
```

But this does not work either.

Comment: Within your R code, can you locate the reference to "data.csv" and include it here?  I'm almost certain this is a relative path issue.

Comment: Yes, but it is an absolute Path: rawdata <- read.csv2("G:/23BLW/231/Allgemeines/R-Statistik/Shiny-Apps/Auswertungen Wohnungseigentum/shiny01_we_data.csv", na.strings = "", encoding = "UTF-8", strip.white = TRUE)

Comment: Hmm - I take it your error ` "G:/ [path to file] /data.csv":`  actually reads ` "G:/ [path to file] /shiny01_we_data.csv":`?

Comment: One thing to try, when running shiny apps from a batch file I tend to use:  `"C:\[R PATH]\Rscript.exe" -e "shiny::runApp('[App folder]', launch.browser = TRUE)"`

Comment: When trying this, the console just pops up for a milisecond and nothing happens... I thought, the PAUSE command should keep the console open?

Comment: Yes - `pause` or `cmd /k` at the end should keep the console open.

Comment: Why is a batch file used at all if it contains only the command line to run `RScript.exe` for interpreting your R script and the pause the processing of the batch file until a key is pressed? I do not really see any reason for not using a shortcut file which would give you the full control about all parameters which can be used on running a Windows console application like `RScript.exe` by the Windows shell (`explorer.exe`) with the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw).

Comment: The shortcut file (`.lnk` file as most shortcuts in Windows Start menu and on Windows Desktop) should have the property __Start in__ configured with `G:\ [path to script]` and property __Target__ is either `"C:\ [path to R] \Rscript.exe" "G:\ [path to script] \app.R"` or `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /K "C:\ [path to R] \Rscript.exe" "G:\ [path to script] \app.R"` if `explorer.exe` on execution of the shortcut should call `CreateProces` to run `cmd.exe` which calls `CreateProcess` to run `Rscript.exe` and when the execution of `Rscript.exe` finished __keeps__ running for seeing the output.

Comment: You can read on the referenced Microsoft documentation page that the process calling `CreateProcess` to run an executable defines with the parameter `lpCurrentDirectory` (long pointer to current working directory path string) the current working directory for a process which can be of course any directory. No script should ever expect that the current directory on execution is the directory containing the script file. That is never guaranteed. The script should determined itself in which directory is stored the script file.

Comment: The script should next concatenate the script file directory path with all file/folder strings for referencing all other files/folders in same directory with their absolute and fully qualified names. Then the script works like most good coded programs which work independent on which directory is the current working directory on start of the executable respectively the script interpreter executable.